# Protect trim finish during installation

Tags: trim, finish, nailing

When using a nail gun to install freshly stained and finished trim,  i want to make sure i don't damage the finish.  In concerned that pressing the  nail gun up against the surface will cause marks.

What's a good way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most nail guns come with rubber bumpers or you can get them from the manufacturer. You can also use a piece of cardboard over the trim and move it along as you go.

Comment: Finish nailers, in particular should have a rubber protective piece. I was quite surprised to find that my _framing_ nailer also came with a protective plastic nose piece.

Comment: @FreeMan  Hey.... studs and rafters want to look nice too...

Comment: Yeah... sure... we'll go with that...  :)